# Schedular Method Return to form of Openrp

Tags: openerp-7

I have an scheduler method of OpenERP. I want to return data to every seconds to Form.

My method like that.

```
def hello(self, cr, uid, context=None):
    now = datetime.now()
    cr.execute('select employee_id,count from late_to_leave (%s,%s)', (now.month, now.year))
    datas = cr.fetchall()
    for data in datas:
        id = data[0]
        count = data[1]
        print 'id is ....',id
        print 'count is ....',count
```

I want to return data to form of hr.attendance.

What should i do.?Help Me.

Answer (score 0):

In you scenario
You should require to set the scheduled action in OpenERP and your method will be defined and called as filed.function() fields same method and its arguments as scheduled action form 
view  where you can set the OpenERP Scheduled Action.

**the functionality can be accessed via the field of your form view.**

**Just check out My simple Schedule action Action For Birthday Schedular for  hr.employee model.**

[image]

You can see that the scheduled action in OpenERP 7.0
You  can click Setting Menu

> > Technical >>Schedular >>Scheduled Actions